# ggplot2::scale_size_area() not mapping zero to zero area?

Tags: r, ggplot2

From the documentation of `ggplot2::scale_size_area()`, I read that

> `scale_size_area()` ensures that a value of 0 is mapped to a size of 0.

However, in this simple example, I still see points where there zeros are. Is this a bug or am I interpreting this wrong?

```r
library(ggplot2)

table(1:3, 1:3) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  ggplot() +
  aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, size=Freq) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_area()
```

#### Data

```r
table(1:3, 1:3) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
print()
```

```
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    1    1    1
2    2    1    0
3    3    1    0
4    1    2    0
5    2    2    1
6    3    2    0
7    1    3    0
8    2    3    0
9    3    3    1
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that ggplot2 is drawing a point with zero area but non-zero stroke, so it is effectively drawing a tiny circle around nothing.

The shapes in geom_point() typically have both an outline and a fill; shapes 19-25 give you separate control of these, but they all have a stroke parameter to control how heavy the outline appears (if at all).

Compare

```
ggplot(data.frame(a = 0:5), aes(a, a, size = a)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_area()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data.frame(a = 0:5), aes(a, a, size = a)) +
  geom_point(stroke = 0) +
  scale_size_area()
```

[image]